# Php, inheritance, late static binding, unexpected calling chain

Tags: php, oop

consider this code:

```
class C
{
    public function get()
    {
        echo 'C';
        static::get();
    }

    public function save()
    {
        self::get();
    }
}

class B extends C
{
    public function get()
    {
        echo 'B';
        static::get();
    }
}

class A extends B
{
    public function get()
    {
        echo 'A';
    }
}

$x = new A();
$x->save();
```

it echoes `CA` while I was expected `CBA`

Comment: You don't have any static method in your code!

Comment: `static::get()` in `C` isn't referencing it's immediate child (`B`), it's referencing the top level child in the inheritance chain (`A`) for $x.... which is what it's supposed to do

Comment: and how to work it around?

Comment: First way to work it round is to actually understand how inheritance actually works.... perhaps change the save() method to call static get(), to modify the gets to call parent::get() before displaying their own output

Comment: Late static binding isn't a method for working up an inheritance tree, it is a jump to the top of the inheritance tree (from anywhere in the tree to the intantiated class).... it's not simply the reverse to parent:: which works down the tree one level at a time

Answer (score 1):

To get this to work the way you want, reverse the logic - get your save to call the `static::get()` so it will start at the top of the inheritence tree; and use calls to `parent::get()` in each inherited class in the tree (except the base level) before echoing its own output

```
class C
{
    public function get()
    {
        echo 'C';
    }

    public function save()
    {
        static::get();
    }
}

class B extends C
{
    public function get()
    {
        parent::get();
        echo 'B';
    }
}

class A extends B
{
    public function get()
    {
        parent::get();
        echo 'A';
    }
}

$x = new A();
$x->save();
```

[Demo](http://3v4l.org/J96NZ)